# Composable Ractive js component

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I'm working on a Ractive js component that represents a table. It works ok but recently I added some functionality: filters, status bar, left column checkboxes, table header. This table component is used throughout the application everywhere.

**The problem is that in different places I need only some combination of these functions. In the current implementation I have a lot of ifs in the template and I want to get rid of them.**

At the moment I want to use the [decorator pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) but have no idea how to implement this especially with the fact that I need to mess with the core table template.

Table template:

```
{{#if status_bar}}
<table class="list-status">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="{{.select_all}}"></td>
        <td>
          {{#if has_filters}}
            <span>Показать:</span>
            {{#each filters:i}}
              <button on-tap="@this.fire('activateFilter', event, i)" {{#if active}}class="active"{{/if}}>{{title}}</button>
            {{/each}}
          {{/if}}
          {{#if ready}}
            <span class="badge lists-badge">{{ collection.total_count }}</span>
            {{#if selected.length > 0}}
              <span class="badge lists-badge" style="background-color: red;">{{ selected.length }}</span>
            {{/if}}
          {{/if}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
{{/if}}

<table class="{{class}}">
  {{#if header}}
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {{^hideSelectColumn}}
          <th></th>
        {{/hideSelectColumn}}
        {{#each titles}}
          <th class={{class}}>{{title}}</th>
        {{/each}}
      </tr>
    </thead>
  {{/if}}
  <tbody>
    {{#if ready}}
      {{#each diff_create:i}}
        <tr class="just-created">
          {{^hideSelectColumn}}
            <td class="{{firstColumnClass}}">
              <div style="position: relative;"></div>
            </td>
          {{/hideSelectColumn}}
          {{>pending}}
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
      {{#if diff_create.length > 0}}
        <tr>
          <td colspan={{column_count}}></td>
        </tr>
      {{/if}}
      {{#each page_models}}
        <tr {{#if mfd}} class='mfd' {{/if}}>
          {{^hideSelectColumn}}
            <td class="{{firstColumnClass}}">
              <input type="checkbox" class="list-checkbox" name='{{selected}}' value='{{@index}}'/>
              <div style="position: relative;"></div>
            </td>
          {{/hideSelectColumn}}
          {{>content}}
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
      {{^page_models}}
        <tr>
          <td style='text-align:center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px' colspan={{column_count}}>Пусто!</td>
        </tr>
      {{/}}
    {{/if}}
    {{^ready}}
      <tr>
        <td style='text-align:center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px' colspan={{column_count}}>Загрузка...</td>
      </tr>
    {{/ready}}
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="pages">
  {{#if pages_more_than_one}}
    <ul class="pagination">
      {{#if has_prev_page}}
        <li class="arrow-left"><a on-tap='prevPage'><span class="icon-arrow-left4"></span></a></li>
      {{/if}}
      {{#each pages}}
        <li class='{{@index+1==current_page ? "active": ""}}'><a on-tap='@this.fire("goToPage", @index+1)'>{{@index+1}}</a></li>
      {{/each}}
      {{#if has_next_page}}
        <li class="arrow-right"><a on-tap='nextPage'><span class="icon-arrow-right8"></span></a></li>
      {{/if}}
    </ul>
  {{/if}}
  <div class="pages-count">
    <select class="form-control" value="{{collection.perpage}}">
      <option value='2'>2</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='10'>10</option>
      <option value='15'>15</option>
      <option value='20'>20</option>
      <option value='25'>25</option>
    </select>&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ractive has [named yields](https://ractive.js.org/api/#yield) where you can define placeholders in your layout and let the consuming component define what goes in there. Think of it like a layouting mechanism.

A simple example is a modal, where you have a header, body and footer which may be different for each instance. A modal component could be defined only as the layout of the modal (think empty bootstrap modal) and a bunch of yields resembling insertable positions.

```
const Modal = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal__header">{{yield header }}</div>
      <div class="modal__body">{{yield body }}</div>
      <div class="modal__footer">{{yield footer }}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
```

On the consuming component, you use the layout component and define what goes in those positions. Note that the yield contents can be *anything*, even other components.

```
const Page = Ractive.extend({
  components: { Modal },
  template: `
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page__stuff">
        ...
      </div>

      <Modal>
        {{#partial header }}
          This is the header
        {{/partial}}

        {{#partial body }}
          This is the body
        {{/partial}}

        {{#partial footer }}
          This is the footer
        {{/partial}}
      </Modal>

    </div>
  `
});
```

In your case, you can break up your table into components (i.e. filters, status bar, left column checkboxes, table header) and define a layout component. Then, whenever you need it, you use the layout component, stick into it whatever you want wherever you want.

A more advanced feature is [Anchors](https://ractive.js.org/api/#anchors). Together with [`ractive.attachChild()`](https://ractive.js.org/api/#ractiveattachchild) and [`ractive.link()`](https://ractive.js.org/api/#ractivelink), you can attach components to anchors manually, on-the-fly. It's essentially how Ractive mounts components and binds data when it sees a component on the template. Except this time, the functionality is exposed on the API.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph, tried this with filters and it works! What do you think about event handling in this case? For now I'm directly changing the shared collection in the Filters component, maybe it's better to handle events in the table itself?

Comment: @Maxim In cases like this, I'd have the components not modify data. I'd have them emit events and let the consuming component (`Page` in the answer) handle data manipulation in reaction to the event. This keeps the components generic, while moving all logic to one place. I think in the React space, they call these ["presentational" and "container" components.](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)